# How do you add winjs to a cordova project?

Tags: javascript, cordova, winjs

I've made a cordova project but I can't find any documentation on how to add winjs to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use this like any other JS library.  Get the CSS and JS files for it from [the download site](http://try.buildwinjs.com/download/GetWinJS/) (see Loose Files) then put them somewhere within your Cordova project's "www" folder, and refer to them in your index.html using relative URLs.

For example if I put them in "www/res/winjs" I would then need script and link tags like so in index.html:

```
<link href="res/winjs/ui-light.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="res/winjs/base.js"></script>
<script src="res/winjs/ui.js"></script>
```

You can then use WinJS like you normally would as per the documentation on the [Microsoft site](http://try.buildwinjs.com/tutorial/1Basics/intro/).